# mysql get query by named variable

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a new mysql table, i want to get the values by named variable.

in the below code `select * from test where name := animalname;` fails to run in mysql workbench. Do advise. thank you so much

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into test(name) values ('bat');
insert into test(name) values ('cat');
insert into test(name) values ('rat');

SET @animalname := 'cat';
select * from test where name := animalname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from test where name = @animalname;
```

`:=` actually sets a variable. You want to compare in your SELECT so use `=`.
And you missed the `@`